# ExpressJS Route hanging and timing out

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple example that I am following.

For some reason the request always times out, wondering if you have any ideas why this could be happening.

```
// server.js

// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port



//load the model
var Bear     = require('./models/bear');


// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});


router.route('/bears')

    // create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
        bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

        // save the bear and check for errors
        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            //res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
            res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   

        });

    });


// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

// more routes for our API will happen here

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Let me know what you think. Essentially I can do GETS no problem, but when I get to /bears and do a POST x-www-form-urlencoded with a param name 'Klaus' it simply hangs. I can't understand why.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: Are you using [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser?_ga=1.151748473.1795931354.1444833875)?

Comment: Yes, using body-parser.  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Have you tried `bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})`? Perhaps showing more of your code will help.

Comment: tried it with extended:false, same behaviour.

Comment: Is the endpoint you're trying to post to at **/api/bears**?

Comment: The only thing that looks odd to me is `router.route('/bears').post(function(req, res) {...})`. Try changing it to `router.post('/bears', function(req, res) {...})` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: If I copy your code (except remove the bear.save() mongoose call), the route works fine.  This leads me to believe that the problem is actually with your database call.  If it just times out, that means that your callback isn't getting executed for whatever reason - your route only returns a response if a bear saves or has an error while saving.

Incidentally, your route as it stand will try to send a response twice if it encounters an error while saving your bear.  You should have it return out if there's an error to prevent it trying to send a JSON call.

Comment: The router.route.post is part of the express router model - it allows you to define multiple verbs on a single route in an easy to read fashion.

Comment: I know, but this one looked odd to me. Probably because he doesn't use it later on the GET route.

Comment: The bear.js file is only this var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);